# How to use style created in mapbox studio in android code?

Tags: android, json, mapbox, mapbox-android

I want to create a style in mapbox studio. Lets say specifying blur effect, zoom etc. I can export this style as a link or as a .json file. And I want to use the style properties in android code for a specific CircleLayer.

I know I can set properties in java code one by one for a layer. But I want to apply entire style that was created in mapbox studio and which is represented in json format.

Mapbox studio where I create set of style properties.

[image]

And a piece of code with CircleLayer

[image]

Comment: `I can export this style as a link or as a .json file` afterwards you load this definition inside your map with MapboxMap#setStyleUrl("someUrl")

Comment: I already use satellite style. Do you mean that by setStyleUrl() I'm actually adding new style on top of the previous style? 

And I'm looking for a way to apply simple style to 1 layer, not to entire map.

Comment: You have a misconception how styles work. Style is the parent that has the  layers and sources. You can go online to Mapbox Studio and create a new style based on the sattellite streets style and add layers/sources to it. Use that style url to load your map.

Answer (score 0):

As [Tobrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281750/tobrun) pointed out, I had misconception about styles. What I wanted to do is to make blur effect on CicleLayer. And I did it by applying "circleBlur" propety to my layer.

```
circleBlur(Function.zoom(Stops.exponential(
                        Stop.stop(16, circleBlur(0.8f)),
                        Stop.stop(17.9, circleBlur(1.2f)),
                        Stop.stop(CLICKABLE_TREE_ZOOM_LEVEL, circleBlur(0f))
                ).withBase(1f))
```